# Netlify / Gatsby / React - I need to have pages that start with '?&'

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I need to create webpages that start with '?&' for example:

www.example.com/?&testwebaddress

When I create js files that start with '?&', React does not allow me to compile. I am using the following:

React
Gatsby
to be deployed in Netlify

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What requires you to have this type of url routing?

Comment: I am trying to create dynamic pages using Gatsby. I think I have to study more Gatsby on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

This won't actually work because `?` is a special delimiting character in a URL. The content after it is called the query string, where parameters can be passed to the server. In the query string, the ampersand (`&`) is a special character that delimits those parameters.

The result is that your URL gets parsed differently than you’re expecting:

[image: url parsing results]

For what it's worth, this is universal, not related to Gatsby.

---

*Thanks to [freeformatter.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/url-parser-query-string-splitter.html) for the handy parser that is shown in the screenshot above.*

Comment: Thanks for this! I am trying to create Dynamic sites but I guess Gatsby is not the way to go. Thanks again!

Comment: @AbrielJohnGabriel As I said, what you're trying to do has nothing to do with Gatsby, but is in fact due to the specification for URLs (`?` and `&` are reserved characters)